# gdb dir command and source path -- what are $cdir, $cwd?

Tags: c, gdb

when I do `(gdb) dir n m`

it outputs following

```
 Source directories searched: /home/fawad/Desktop/linux-debug/linux-5.12.6/n:/home/fawad/Desktop/linux-debug/linux-5.12.6/m:$cdir:$cwd
```

above output apparently says that gdb search these two directories

1)

```
/home/fawad/Desktop/linux-debug/linux-5.12.6/n
```

`
2)

```
/home/fawad/Desktop/linux-debug/linux-5.12.6/m
```

is doing `dir n m` inside gdb means `gdb` search two directories n and m?

and what is `$cdir:$cwd` are? should they be read like `cdir` directory (also searched at cdir/ directory) and (also `cwd` means also searched at $cwd/)

if this is correct then did it search 4 directories?

another example, when I do

```
 dir drivers
```

which directory be searched

on this page https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html
it says

> ‘$cdir’ causes GDB to search within the compilation directory, if one is recorded in the debug information. If no compilation directory is recorded in the debug information then ‘$cdir’ is ignored.

so basically if my program.o is in /home/user786/test_program/program.o then `$cdir` will be /home/user786/test_program/

what `$cwd` will be?
in the link it says

> ‘$cwd’ is not the same as ‘.’
> the former(? is it $cdir) tracks the current working directory as it changes during your GDB session. while the latter is immediately expanded to the current directory at the time you add an entry to the source path

does above line says that if i have a source program named `program1` at location `/home/fwd/program1`  and `program1` directory contains header files inside `/home/fwd/program1/headerFiles then  is $cwd can be $cdir:/headerFiles/ ? so total path of headerFiles will be $cdir:/$cwd contains header files?

Question

and can I use $cdir and $cwd with list command like `list $cdir:/cwd/header_file_1.h` and break command.

How do I know if some object file of program1 is inside program1/program1_part1 contains program_part1.o because that I may want to debug that?

how to set $cwd? before running  gdb `list` command

Answer (score 0):

> so basically if my program.o is in /home/user786/test_program/program.o then $cdir will be /home/user786/test_program/

Incorrect: `$cdir` has nothing to do with where the *object* file is; it's the *compilation* directory.

If you have sources in e.g. `/foo/bar/src` and you compile in `/tmp/foo/build` with the command line `gcc -g -c /foo/bar/src/subdir/a.c -o subdir/a.o`, the `$cdir` will be `/tmp/foo/build`.

> what $cwd will be?

`$cwd` is the current directory. If you invoke GDB in `/tmp`, then `$cwd` will be `/tmp`. If you change current directory with e.g. `(gdb) cd /tmp/foo/build`, then `$cwd` will become `/tmp/foo/build`.